# Unsafe to not provide full path to powershell script?

Tags: powershell, path-injection

Is the following statement in a batch file unsafe?

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File .\test.ps1
```

`test.ps1` is located in the same folder as the batch file.

Is it possible to add something in the default powershell profile script (`C:\Users\Username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`) so that another `test.ps1` is loaded (e.g. a `test.ps1` in a `%temp%` folder, instead of `test.ps1` in the same folder as the batch file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.\test.ps1 is a relative reference to a file in the current subdirectory.

There is no way that I am aware of to change how the OS will treat that path reference via a PS profile.

Note that if your batch file is located in the system path, and it is invoked from a directory other than the one where it is located, the .\test.ps1 reference will fail.

In that case, you need to use a full path to reference the file EG -File c:\scripts\test.ps1